# How do I display a url to a pdf file as a jpeg image in a browser using php?

Tags: php, mysql, url, pdf, jpeg

I have a MySQL database which has several urls to pdf files (like path/.../file.pdf) and I want to display them in my browser as jpeg images. I've looked all over the web but couldn't find a solution. does anyone know how to do this? Any help is appreciated. 
Currently I have two files: index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/pdf; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Something</h1>
    <img src="newindex.php" alt=" image" /></body></html>
```

and newindex.php:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/pdf;');

    $con = mysql_connect("someurl",
            "xxx","xxxx");

    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }


    mysql_select_db("xxx", $con)or die("cannot select DB");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT pdfurl FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Code LIKE 'YY'");

    if($result === FALSE) {
        echo "nooooo";
    }
    echo "hey";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {    
       echo '<img name="myimage" src="'.$row['pdfurl'].'" width="60" height="60" alt="word" />';
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($con); ?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to take text (the URLS?) with php and convert it to an image?  I believe there are libraries for this (GD or ImageMagik), but nothing I've really played with.

Comment: If you're talking about creating an image of text, please do NOT use JPEG.  JPEG is only for photographs, and if you use it on text, line art, or anything else that is not an actual photographic image, you will get ugly image artifacts.  Use PNG instead.

Comment: jpeg has utility outside of photographs, but generally this is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display it as a JPEG image you have to convert it into one. There are several software products availabe that can do this, including [GDlib](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/). They differ primarily in the level of integration into PHP and image quality.

In your HTML you would then output the `img` tag with a PHP script as the `src` that does the converting and caching using the mentioned software:

```
echo '<img src="converter.php?'.$pdf_name.'" />';
```

In some browsers you can display the pdf directly in the page, but this is done using the `embed` tag instead of the `img` tag and is generally not suitable for a thumbnail-like view.

Comment: +1 for passing url as variable, but i don't think additional libraries are necessary. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php

Comment: That function *is* from GDlib. :)

Answer (score 0):

your img src will be a php page, and will probably utilize image_create().  Example here: http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/create-image.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your http server.

Your http server needs to use php for .jpg processing.

Lighttpd for [example](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI#Examples).
Replace `.php` with `.jpg`

**OR** (the better option)

you could use a rewrite option to rewrite `.jpg` as `.php`

Edit: of corse you need to print an real image (binary) as output in your script.
use AndreKR answer

Comment: I dont think thats the problem it will only create problems